# react.js cannot read the image by parameter

Tags: reactjs

I am loading the JSON file and read the file path one by one. When i replace the file path by {props.image}, it has an error.

It is working:

```
<Card.Img style={imgStyle} variant="top" src={require("./abc.jpg").default}  />
```

It is not working

```
          <Card.Img style={imgStyle} variant="top" src={require({props.image}).default}  />
```

Comment: What is props.image

Comment: props.image is the file path. In this case, props.image = ./abc.jpg

Comment: May I ask why you doing a `require` instead of just a path to an image so on component load user gets the image from the server separately? That would enable lazy loading

Answer (score 0):

`props` are reactive. And I don't think, require is at all. So even it the props.image is being changed. The output of require is not changing, so `Card.Img`, is not updating change.

Try something like this :

```
src={props.image==='' ? require('./some_default.png').default : require({props.image}).default
```

*I guess you are familiar with `JSON copy` dilemma*

Comment: So in the Card.Img, I cannot use props.image? Is there any method that allows using a parameter? And I am a beginner at react.js.

Comment: it says you have copied images to public folder, but this is not an elegant solution always... i'll try an implement my solution on local, if i do, iwll share it with you all..

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i put the file in the public folder, problem solved